# Unable to render LineChart in Laravel 5.1 created using Lavacharts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have followed the tutorial https://github.com/kevinkhill/lavacharts to render the chart in my application based on Laravel 5.1. But Unable to render it. It gives me error ***LineChart('Stocks') was not found in View***. Below is my controller code & view code. What changes are required to fix this issue?

ChartController.php

```
public function generatecharts()
{

$lava = new Lavacharts;
$stocksTable = $lava->DataTable();

 $stocksTable->addDateColumn('Day of Month')
            ->addNumberColumn('Projected')
            ->addNumberColumn('Official');




// Random Data For Example
for ($a = 1; $a < 30; $a++)
{
    $rowData = array(
      "2014-8-$a", rand(800,1000), rand(800,1000)
    );

    $stocksTable->addRow($rowData);
}

  $Chart = $lava->LineChart('Stocks')
                ->setOptions(array(
                    'datatable' => $stocksTable,
                    'title' => 'Stock Market Trends'
                  ));

return view('pages.analytics');

}
```

analytics.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title') analytics:: @parent @stop
@section('content')



<div class="row">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h2>Welcome to analytics</h2>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="stock-div"></div>
echo $lava->render('LineChart', 'Stocks', 'stock-div');
@linechart('Stocks', 'stocks-div');


@endsection
```

Answer (score 5):

1) It stated in the [documentation](http://lavacharts.com/#install-laravel) that if you are using Laravel, you need to change

```
$lava-> to \Lava:: (the slash is important)
```

2) Actually this line of code:

```
 echo $lava->render('LineChart', 'Stocks', 'stock-div');
```

is equivalent to this line:

```
 @linechart('Stocks', 'stocks-div');
```

So you have a repeating code here (just delete one line).

You have 3 options to put in your view:

You can use PHP tag:

```
<?php echo \Lava::render('LineChart', 'Stocks', 'stock-div'); ?>
```

or you can use this:

```
{!! \Lava::render('LineChart', 'Stocks', 'stock-div') !!}
```

or this simplified version

```
@linechart('Stocks', 'stocks-div');
```

Solution:

**ChartController.php**

```
public function generatecharts()
{

$stocksTable = \Lava::DataTable();

 $stocksTable->addDateColumn('Day of Month')
            ->addNumberColumn('Projected')
            ->addNumberColumn('Official');




// Random Data For Example

for ($a = 1; $a < 30; $a++)
{
    $rowData = array(
      "2014-8-$a", rand(800,1000), rand(800,1000)
    );

    $stocksTable->addRow($rowData);
}

  $Chart = \Lava::LineChart('Stocks')
                ->setOptions(array(
                    'datatable' => $stocksTable,
                    'title' => 'Stock Market Trends'
                  ));

return view('pages.analytics');

}
```

**analytics.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title') analytics:: @parent @stop
@section('content')



<div class="row">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h2>Welcome to analytics</h2>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="stock-div"></div>

{!! \Lava::render('LineChart', 'Stocks', 'stock-div') !!}

@endsection
```

Comment: What to do in Laravel 4.2?

Answer (score 1):

HERE IS THE CODE FOR **LAVACHARTS 3.0 AND LARAVEL 5.2**

**Controller**

```
    $stocksTable = \Lava::DataTable();
    $stocksTable->addDateColumn('Day of Month')
        ->addNumberColumn('Projected')
        ->addNumberColumn('Official');

    // Random Data For Example
    for ($a = 1; $a < 30; $a++) {
        $stocksTable->addRow(["2014-8-$a", rand(800, 1000), rand(800, 1000)]);
    }

    //DON'T pass $Chart object to view, you get it via its label
    //options here: http://lavacharts.com/#datatables
    $Chart = \Lava::LineChart('this_is_the_label', $stocksTable, [
        'title'    => 'This works in laravel 5.2',
        'fontSize' => 24,
    ]);
```

**View**

```
<div id="stock-div"></div>
{!! \Lava::render('LineChart', 'this_is_the_label', 'stock-div') !!}
```